Import TensorFlow as Bazel dependency for C++ project
I'm starting a new C++ project that requires TensorFlow. I would like to configure a way to import TensorFlow from github without having to build it manually for each environment.
I'm using Bazel to build my project and manage dependencies because TensorFlow is using it and it seems less of a struggle to import it with Bazel. On top of that I'm using bzlmod (the new way of importing modules).
I can't find any good documentation or tutorial to import it properly. I'm quite new to C++ builds practices (coming from java / node world). I've tried TensorFlow Serving way of importing TensorFlow as mentioned in some posts. But nothing works for me.
As for now I have this error when trying to sync Bazel on CLion :
error loading package '@@org_tensorflow~//tensorflow/core': Unable to find package for @@[unknown repo 'local_config_cuda' requested from @@org_tensorflow~]//cuda:build_defs.bzl: The repository '@@[unknown repo 'local_config_cuda' requested from @@org_tensorflow~]' could not be resolved: No repository visible as '@local_config_cuda' from repository '@@org_tensorflow~'. and referenced by '//src/main:my_project_main'

I'm on a MacBook, that might explain why it misses some cuda stuff. How can I toggle on and off cuda functions based on the OS I'm running on ? I might need it later on production but disabled on my mac.
Here is my current configuration :
registry/
  modules/
    org_tensorflow/
      2.15.1/
        MODULE.bazel
        source.json
      metadata.json
    bazel_registry.json
src/
  main/
    BUILD.bazel
    main.cc
.bazelrc
MODULE.bazel
WORKSPACE.bazel

I put aside the registry part that just specify the url to get the archive from as it seems to be working properly. The archive is well retrieve from github and I seem to have correct access to its files.
My .bazelrc looks like this :
# Enable Bzlmod for every Bazel command
common --enable_bzlmod --registry=https://bcr.bazel.build --registry=file://%workspace%/registry --experimental_repo_remote_exec

My MODULE.bazel looks like this
module(
    name = "my_project",
    repo_name = "my_project",
)

bazel_dep(name = "bazel_skylib", version = "1.6.1")
bazel_dep(name = "rules_java", version = "7.5.0")
bazel_dep(name = "rules_python", version = "0.31.0")
bazel_dep(name = "org_tensorflow", version = "2.15.1")

My WORKSPACE.bazel look like this :
load("@rules_python//python:repositories.bzl", "py_repositories", "python_register_toolchains")

py_repositories()

python_register_toolchains(
    name = "python",
    ignore_root_user_error = True,
    python_version = "3.9",
)

load("@python//:defs.bzl", "interpreter")
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "package_annotation", "pip_parse")

NUMPY_ANNOTATIONS = {
    "numpy": package_annotation(
        additive_build_content = """\
filegroup(
    name = "includes",
    srcs = glob(["site-packages/numpy/core/include/**/*.h"]),
)
cc_library(
    name = "numpy_headers",
    hdrs = [":includes"],
    strip_include_prefix="site-packages/numpy/core/include/",
)
""",
    ),
}

pip_parse(
    name = "pypi",
    annotations = NUMPY_ANNOTATIONS,
    python_interpreter_target = interpreter,
    requirements_lock = "@org_tensorflow//:requirements_lock_3_9.txt",
)

load("@pypi//:requirements.bzl", "install_deps")

install_deps()

load("@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace3.bzl", "tf_workspace3")

tf_workspace3()

load("@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace2.bzl", "tf_workspace2")

tf_workspace2()

load("@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace1.bzl", "tf_workspace1")

tf_workspace1()

load("@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace0.bzl", "tf_workspace0")

tf_workspace0()

I tried to copied the way TensorFlow Serving include and configure TensorFlow and the way TensorFlow's WORKSPACE is setup. But I have no real idea of what I'm doing.
Then I'm importing the code in my project with my src/main/BUILD.bazel like that :
cc_binary(
    name = "my_project_main",
    srcs = [
        "main.cc",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
)

By the way I don't know which target to specify as dependency. TensorFlow Serving uses @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:lib. Do you know which target is suited for my use case ? I will need to use basic TensorFlow classes in my C++ code such as tf.Tensor(), tf.float(), etc...
If you have any advice, solutions, thank you !
-- EDIT --
I've created a public GitHub repo so you can see and test by yourself : https://github.com/lucien-perouze/tensorflow_bazel
I've slightly changed some files since my post to test new things but still get the same error : ERROR: error loading package '@@org_tensorflow~//tensorflow/core': Unable to find package for @@[unknown repo 'local_config_cuda' requested from @@org_tensorflow~]//cuda:build_defs.bzl: The repository '@@[unknown repo 'local_config_cuda' requested from @@org_tensorflow~]' could not be resolved: No repository visible as '@local_config_cuda' from repository '@@org_tensorflow~’.
I've tried to run the Tensorflow python configuration file in an module extension but it seems that the extension is not called at all since my print() isn't showed in logs. What am I doing wrong ?

Hi @lucien When you're setting up dependencies in your BUILD.bazel file, make sure you're using the right target. For accessing basic TensorFlow classes in C++, you can use the target @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:tensorflow. This target provides the core TensorFlow library that includes essential functionalities for your C++ project. If Still you Face the error feel free to ask.
